# Why Newtonian mechanics works in cosmology?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, gravity, newtonian-gravity, space-expansion

Could anyone please provide an intuitive explanation of why Newtonian mechanics can be used to describe our universe at extremely large scales?

A typical explanation goes "since speeds and energy densities of matter are quite low (except inside black holes / neutron stars), GR corrections to Newtonian physics are not needed".

While I agree with the first part of the statement, it is nevertheless not clear to me why we can totally neglect the fact that the gravitational interaction is transmitted at a finite speed, and it may take years for it to propagate between two gravitating objects — basically, each object is attracted toward the point where another object used to be long time ago.

To put it slightly differently, if you study the motion of metal balls on a stretched bed sheet, it is totally not obvious that you can use the same equations once the sheet starts propagating the sag at a significantly slower rate.

One argument could be "if we study virialized objects (i.e. those in a sort of dynamical equilibrium), the Newtonian approximation is OK, since after a zillion years, any object will be replaced by another, approximately same object, which would exert the same force". Sounds reasonable but still sketchy.

Comment: Who told you that Newtonian mechanics works in cosmology? How does it explain the observed accelerating expansion of the universe?

Comment: I didn't mean in my question stuff like inflation and early universe. It was more about things like rotation of galaxies / clusters.

Comment: I think you need to specify exactly the applications you have in mind and differentiate between, cosmology, astrophysics, astronomy. And even within the branches not all applications use the same tools.

Comment: “*basically, each object is attracted toward the point where another object used to be long time ago*” - This is generally incorrect. For example, the Earth is attracted to the real time position of the Sun, not to its retarded position where the Sun was 8 minutes ago. This fact however does not contradict gravity being limited by the speed of light. It is just how the math works out in established cases.

Comment: So even for accelerating objects in the curved spacetime the force exerted on object 1 by object 2 is always tangent to the geodesic between 1 and 2? What if there are several of those?

Comment: Certain cosmological predictions of GR can be reproduced within Newtonian mechanics. This has been first observed by Milne in 1934. For a contemporary review see Jordan (2005), https://arxiv.org/pdf/astro-ph/0309756.pdf. In footnote 1 he gives more references.

Answer (score 4):

Special and general relativity corrections are needed for [the GPS system](http://www.astronomy.ohio-state.edu/%7Epogge/Ast162/Unit5/gps.html) to work.  It all depends on what accuracy of variables one wants to work with. The GPS needs meters and seconds.

Cosmology works with light year distances and light years. Newtonian physics is a good approximation where the gravitational field is  weak, and the relative distances and times are withing measurement errors, that is all.

Comment: "Neutonian physics is a good approximation where the gravitational field is weak" - so why don't we add to this "and distances are small"?

Comment: @mavzolej: I'd say it's more "the difference between the derivative with respect to retarded time and that with respect to actual time is small" than "the distances are small".  If things are moving non-relativisticially, and have been over their whole life, for these purposes, it doesn't matter how far away they are.  After all, for a true electrostatics problem, the field holds its value to infinity, forever.

Comment: @mavzolej as I say in my answer, distances are relative to what one  is measuring. The newtonian solutions are no good in our planetary system where we want accuracies of meter and seconds.

Comment: So do you say that, even though signals between objects in a system may propagate for many years, they move so slow relative to each other that this seemingly huge delay can be neglected?

Comment: Yes, when ome measures time  in light years  one light year  error  is not important for conclusions on fits of data to theory

Answer (score 2):

I don't think anyone uses Newtonian gravity in cosmology. For modelling galaxies or even clusters of galaxies, sure, it's a reasonable approximation. But the models for the whole universe are all based on general relativity.

Comment: Galaxies and galaxy clusters was precisely the scale I was asking about. In this case the distances can be of order of many light years, so the criterion of weakness of gravitational field does not seem to necessarily be enough.

Comment: Newtonian Mechanics fail on any structure larger than a solar system.  General Relativity also fails on this scale as well, so neither really works very well.

Comment: What do you mean by "General Relativity also fails on this scale"?

Comment: Could you please explain the contradiction between your answer and comment: first, you say "for modeling galaxies and cluster Newtonian mechanics is OK", but then you say that it fails at structures larger than a solar system. How come?

Comment: User "Gluon soup" is the one who said that it fails on structures larger than a solar system, and that's a dubious claim.

Comment: When relative velocities are much smaller than the speed of gravity, and pressure and density are "small", Newtonian mechanics is usually a good approximation. There are some anomalous cases in astronomy where Newtonian calculations of e.g. galaxy rotation don't match with observation. The most widely accepted explanation for this is dark matter, but a minority view is that these observations require non-Newtonian gravity, either more detailed GR calculations or something beyond GR. This is still an active area of research.